# The result of Monte Carlo standard error in my code could be wrong in R

Tags: r, simulation

I try to compute the Monte Carlo standard error of my estimators. I first got my estimators based on the following repetition of Monte Carlo simulation:

So my code is as follows but the results are weird...

```
#[1] 0.01081287
#[1] 0.007556727
```

Comment: It would help if you could describe the problem more specifically than "the results are weird." What were you expecting? Assume not everyone here knows the ins & outs of the calculation you're doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the definition of MCSE of bias (`theta` in the formula refers to the estimated parameter, i.e., `MLE`)

```
> MCSE_bias_mle <- sqrt(1 / rowSums((MLE - rowMeans(MLE))^2) / (2*choose(N, 2)))

> MCSE_bias_mle
[1] 0.010812870 0.007556727
```

where the 1st and 2nd values are for `mu` and `sigma`, respectively

Comment: @oliver yes you are right. Sorry that I made some mistakes but corrected them now